# What is the point of "ROLLBACK TRANSACTION named_transaction"?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, transactions, rollback

I've read through MSDN on [ROLLBACK TRANSACTION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181299.aspx) and [nesting transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189336.aspx).  While I see the point of `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION savepointname`, I do not understand `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION transactionname`.

1. It only works when `transactionname` is the outermost transaction
2. `ROLLBACK` always rolls back the entire transaction "stack", except in the case of `savepointname`

Basically, as I read the documentation, except in the case of a save point, `ROLLBACK` rolls back all transactions (to `@@TRANCOUNT=0`).  The only difference I can see is this snippet:

> If a ROLLBACK TRANSACTION transaction_name statement using the name of
>   the outer transaction is executed at any level of a set of nested
>   transactions, all of the *nested transactions* are rolled back.
>   If a ROLLBACK WORK or ROLLBACK TRANSACTION statement without a
>   transaction_name parameter is executed at any level of a set of nested
>   transaction, it rolls back all of the nested transactions, including
>   the outermost transaction.

From the reading, this suggests to me that rolling back a named transaction (which must be the name of the outermost transaction), only the nested transactions will be rolled back.  This would give some meaning to rolling back a named transaction.  So I set up a test:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP (id varchar(50))

INSERT INTO #TEMP (id) VALUES ('NO')
SELECT id AS NOTRAN FROM #TEMP
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT AS NOTRAN_TRANCOUNT

BEGIN TRAN OUTERTRAN

INSERT INTO #TEMP (id) VALUES ('OUTER')
SELECT id AS OUTERTRAN FROM #TEMP
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT AS OUTERTRAN_TRANCOUNT

BEGIN TRAN INNERTRAN

INSERT INTO #TEMP (id) VALUES ('INNER')
SELECT id AS INNERTRAN FROM #TEMP
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT AS INNERTRAN_TRANCOUNT

ROLLBACK TRAN OUTERTRAN

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRAN

SELECT id AS AFTERROLLBACK FROM #TEMP
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT AS AFTERROLLBACK_TRANCOUNT

DROP TABLE #TEMP
```

results in (all "X row(s) affected" stuff removed)

```
NOTRAN
--------------------------------------------------
NO

NOTRAN_TRANCOUNT
----------------
0

OUTERTRAN
--------------------------------------------------
NO
OUTER

OUTERTRAN_TRANCOUNT
-------------------
1

INNERTRAN
--------------------------------------------------
NO
OUTER
INNER

INNERTRAN_TRANCOUNT
-------------------
2

AFTERROLLBACK
--------------------------------------------------
NO

AFTERROLLBACK_TRANCOUNT
-----------------------
0
```

Note that there is *no difference* to the output when I change

```
ROLLBACK TRAN OUTERTRAN
```

to simply

```
ROLLBACK TRAN
```

So what is the point of `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION named_transaction`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Save points are exactly as the name implies: 'save points' in the log sequence. The log sequence is always linear. If you rollback to a save point, you rollback *everything* your transaction did between your current log position and the save point. Consider your example:

```
LSN 1: BEGIN TRAN OUTERTRAN
LSN 2: INSERT INTO ...
LSN 3: BEGIN TRAN INNERTRAN
LSN 4: INSERT INTO ...
LSN 5: ROLLBACK TRAN OUTERTRAN
```

At Log Sequence Number (LSN) 1 the OUTERTRAN save point is created. The first INSERT creates LSN 2. Then the INNERTRAN creates a save point with LSN 3. Second INSERT creates a new LSN, 4. The ROLLBACK OUTERTRAN is equivalent to 'ROLLBACK log until the LSN 1'. You cannot 'skip' portions of the log, so you must rollback every operation in the log until LSN 1 (when the save point OUTERTRAN was created) is hit.

On the other hand if at the last operation you would issue ROLLBACK INNERTRAN the engine would roll back until the LSN 3 (where the 'INNERTRAN' save point was inserted in the log) thus preserving LSN 1 and LSN 2 (ie. the first INSERT).

For a practical example of save points see [Exception handling and nested transactions](http://rusanu.com/2009/06/11/exception-handling-and-nested-transactions/).

Comment: OK, I see what you've done. However, I am still curious as to my original point. I get save points and their value, but I'm still confused over rolling back a transaction (not save point) name. An important note, apparently you cannot ROLLBACK an inner transaction. e.g., ROLLBACK TRAN INNERTRAN results in an error, "Cannot roll back INNERTRAN. No transaction or savepoint of that name was found.". This point (about rolling back named nested transactions being disallowed) is in the documentation links I mentioned in the OP.

Comment: `To rollback to INNERTRAN you need to use the syntax 'SAVE TRANSACTION INNERTRAN` which creates a true save point (as opposed to a named transaction). Named transactions are mostly for recovery scenarios (`RESTORE WITH STOPAT OUTERTRAN`)